# "Key Error: -1" while running IF statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to run the below code in a DataFrame. My intention is to include as part of the DataFrame (df) "Buy", "Sell", "Hold" or "Wait" based on the below conditions.

```
for i in range(len(df)):

    if df['sma_fast'][i-1]>df['sma_slow'][i-1] and df['sma_fast'][i-2]<df['sma_slow'][i-2]:
        df['Signal'] = 'Buy'  
    elif df['sma_fast'][i-1]>df['sma_slow'][i-1] and df['sma_fast'][i-2]>df['sma_slow'][i-2]:
        df['Signal'] = 'Hold'
    elif df['sma_fast'][i-1]<df['sma_slow'][i-1] and df['sma_fast'][i-2]>df['sma_slow'][i-2]:
        df['Signal'] = 'Sell'
    elif df['sma_fast'][i-1]<df['sma_slow'][i-1] and df['sma_fast'][i-2]<df['sma_slow'][i-2]:
        df['Signal'] = 'Wait'
    else:
        df['Signal'] = 'nan'
```

But I am getting the following error:

> KeyError: -1

Could you please help me solving this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: `range(stop)` begins at 0. 0-1 = -1 => `KeyError`

Comment: Many thanks ! I fixed the range. Now I found another error, I am just getting "Hold" in the "Signal" column. Could you please help me figuring the issue out? Do you see something wrong in the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `for i in range(len(df)):`
has `i` iterate from values 0 to however big df is.

So initially, when `i` is 0, one of the first things you check to see is `if df['sma_fast'][i-1]>df['sma_slow'][i-1]` and some other stuff. Note that this means you're checking the index of df at ['sma_fast'][-1].

You can't really check an array at a negative index, so Python is complaining with a KeyError.

I'm not too sure what your intended edge cases are, but I would just make some if-statements to get around this issue.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i < 2:
        continue

    if df['sma_fast'][i-1]>df['sma_slow'][i-1] and df['sma_fast'][i-2]<df['sma_slow'][i-2]:
        df['Signal'] = 'Buy'  
    elif df['sma_fast'][i-1]>df['sma_slow'][i-1] and df['sma_fast'][i-2]>df['sma_slow'][i-2]:
        df['Signal'] = 'Hold'
    elif df['sma_fast'][i-1]<df['sma_slow'][i-1] and df['sma_fast'][i-2]>df['sma_slow'][i-2]:
        df['Signal'] = 'Sell'
    elif df['sma_fast'][i-1]<df['sma_slow'][i-1] and df['sma_fast'][i-2]<df['sma_slow'][i-2]:
        df['Signal'] = 'Wait'
    else:
        df['Signal'] = 'nan'
```

This would get rid of your KeyError, but you would need to figure out what you want  happening when i= 0,1.

Comment: Many thanks ! I fixed the range and it is working now. However, now I found another error, I am just getting "Hold" in the "Signal" column. Could you please help me figuring the issue out? Do you see something wrong in the code?

Comment: `range` has a `start` parameter, so instead of `continue`, maybe just start at `2` with `range(2, len(df))`?

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful! The issue is resolved now!